# Dynamic function and dynamic parameter/argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, parameters, arguments

I have this function called `copyToClipboard()`. This takes a parameter called element. This function copies the content of a element by locating its id, selecting and copying the contents.

For instance:

**JS**

```
/*
*  Copy to clipboard fn
*/
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");  
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  var $tempval = $temp.val($(element).text());
  $temp.remove();  

  var $notif = $("<p>");
  $notif.attr("class","notif");
  $("body").append($notif);
  $notif.html('Copied content to clipboard!');
  setTimeout(function() {
      $notif.fadeOut();
      $notif.promise().done(function(){
        this.remove();
      });
  }, 400);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="p1">content of #p1</p>
<p> not me tho </p>
<p id="p2">content of #p2</p>   
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy P1</button>
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p2')">Copy P2</button>
```

I am trying to improve this into a function which generates the buttons dynamically.

My approach so far where I integrated the above function into a new function, iterating over the elements found by ID/Class (IDs in this example),vb generating buttons with the onclick function container the iterated value as a parameter/argument.

```
/*
* generate copy buttons fn
*/
function generateCopyButtons() {

  var links = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('p');
      for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
          var $link = links[i];
          var thisId = $($link).attr('id');     
              if( thisId && thisId !== "null" && thisId !== "undefined" ){                  
                  var $button = document.createElement('button'); // btn
                  $button.innerHTML = 'Copy ' + thisId; //btn text
                  var element = '#' + thisId; // # + id 
                // console.log(element); // works like i want, #p1, #p2

                //how do i pass the element into this function??
                $button.onclick = function(element) {
                    var $temp = $("<input>");                    
                    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    var $tempval = $temp.val($(element).text());
                    $("body").append($temp);
                    $temp.remove();

                var $notif = $("<p>");
                $notif.attr("class","notif");
                $("body").append($notif);
                $notif.html('Copied content to clipboard!');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $notif.fadeOut();
                    $notif.promise().done(function(){
                      $notif.remove();
                    });
                }, 400);
            };
              $($link).prepend($button);              
              // $($thisHashId).remove();
          }
}

}
$(document).ready(function(){
  generateCopyButtons();
});
```

Right now it doesn't show errors and it doesn't work. Using the previous buttons works fine.

[jsfiddle demonstrating problem](https://jsfiddle.net/141nunk6/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lookforangular is was able to update my code.
first selecting all p nodes in the div#links in a foreach loop. This way the click event can be handeled in general instead of selecting single p nodes.

By setting the id as a data-p the click event can use the data-p value as dynamic argument to target the div you want to copy. Feel free to rewrite, use or update this function. Below the code is a link to a working fiddle demonstrating the effect.
Small bonus a message notifies the user of this action.

```
 /*
  * generate copy buttons fn
  */
 function generateCopyButtons() {
   var pNodes = document.querySelectorAll('#links p[id^="p"]');
   pNodes.forEach(function(element) {
     var $button = document.createElement('button'); // btn       
     $button.innerHTML = 'Copy ' + element.id; //btn text
  // for this example we will set the value of data-p dynamically with the id so we have something to target. 
     $button.setAttribute('data-p', element.getAttribute('id'));
     element.prepend($button);

   $($button).on("click", function() {
     var $datap = '"#' + $($button).attr('data-p') + '"';
     //console.log($datap);
     var $temp = $("<input>");
     $("body").append($temp);
     $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
     document.execCommand("copy");
     $temp.remove();

     var $notif = $("<p>");
     $notif.attr("class", "notif");
     $("body").append($notif);
     $notif.html('Copied content to clipboard!');
     setTimeout(function() {
       $notif.fadeOut();
       $notif.promise().done(function() {
         this.remove();
       });
     }, 400);
   });

   });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution include 2 steps.

First get all `<p>` nodes inside the `#links` and filter out those with no id.

```
var pNodes = document.querySelectorAll('#links p[id^="p"]');
pNodes.forEach(function(element){
    var button = document.createElement('button');

    [...] //add button text, etc..

    button.setAttribute('data-p',element.getAttribute('id') );
    element.insertAdjacentHtml('afterend', button);
});
```

A great way to remove unnecessary code is to use a delegate.
When you click any node in the document, by default the event is propagated upwards, this means that `<button>` elements click can be listened from it's parent `#links` node, this will reduce the amount of code by removing the for loop.

```
var node = document.getElementById("links");
node.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "P") {
        //click event target is a <button> node
        //here e.target is the <button> DOM node
        //use e.target.getAttribute('data-p') to retrieve the <p>'s ID
    }
}
```

This solves the need to attach a listener on every button, button generation can be handled in another script/function
I'm not sure if it will work on all browsers (IE)

Comment: thanks i will update my answer with this code later. IE compat is not neccesary thanks. Still looking for a option to pass the dynamic argument into the onclick function.

Comment: i'm not sure where this helps me with generating the arguments, but its a nicer way of writing the loop for sure.

Comment: what kind of arguments are you looking for? have you considered to insert data tag inside the generated p element?

Comment: You could Store all the <p> tags in an array, filter those without an id, and foreach p create a sibling button that got the id parameter inside a `data-p-id` or something, then watch using `e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON"`

Comment: I 'm not trying to generate the p's. What i want is to generate buttons, prepended or appended to the p's (if they have a ID), set this ID ( + # ) as argument of the onclick for each button-> e.g. <p id="p1">...</p> becomes <p id="p1">...</p><button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">...</button> Hope this makes sence

Comment: If you map every p to a button and store the value inside a data tag you can access that id directly inside the button, and by delegation there is no need to include an argument to the function

Comment: thanks i've got it working, however since your answer did not solve the question i cannot accept it.

Comment: Ok, no problem, but can you publish the solved problem so people with your kind of problem may find some clues. Thanks :)